# Is EXE locked (vs DLL)?

Tags: .net, security, dll, exe

If I put all my controls inside the EXE, is it accessible from outside like it would be accessible when it's placed in a DLL?

Comment: It really depends on whether you are talking about CLR vs. unmanaged code, and what kind of controls you are developing - native Win32, ActiveX, Winforms or WPF.

Comment: I am talking about .NET managed EXEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by BobbyShaftoe, it depends on whether you're using managed or unmanaged code, but I'll assume here that you're using unmanaged C or C++.

Basically, a compiled executable (EXE or DLL, in the case of Windows) consists of a bunch of functions and global variables, and each one has a particular location in the executable's logical address space (which gets mapped onto physical memory addresses when the executable is loaded).

If someone knows the address of a particular function or variable in their executable, there's not much you can do to stop them from using it — but in a DLL, that information is actually made available, so people can actually look up your functions (well, the ones you chose to export) by name.

Usually you would provide a header file with your DLL, which would handle this name lookup, so they just have to call the functions as if they were part of their own program.

Comment: Your third paragraph makes no sense to me.  A DLL and an "executable" are both PE files on modern Windows with the ability to export symbols or not to.  In either case you still need to export symbols explicitly if you want them to be "visible" to another user of your PE file.  Or, exported or not, you can resolve the symbol yourself (instead of using `GetProcAddress` on an exported on) and execute the code.  I think you're making a distiction between DLLs and "executables" that simply isn't there.

Comment: Good point. It seems to me, though, that the *purpose* of an EXE (as opposed to a DLL) is more in line with what the OP wants, if he's looking to make the symbols inaccessible. If you can provide some examples of reasons to export symbols in a deployed EXE, this would seem to answer the OP's question better. (I would try myself, but I'm not a Windows programmer, and so would probably miss out the intricacies of the way MS have decided to do it ;-)

Comment: I was talking about managed .NET code, sorry for not mentioning it at first.

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing you're after is this notion of exporting symbols typically, unless you do something explicit, the symbols are not exported when you compile an exe in Windows. Now, if you're talking about .NET then the issue is a little different. However, I notice you tagged this with security; I wouldn't rely on this fact for security purposes. Code injection and so forth attacks are a little more sophisticated than that.